# Modify cells in a raster, that intersect or are inside a polygon without modify the other cells

Tags: python, rasterio, numpy, rioxarray

I have a raster of a DEM (Digital Elevation Model with values in meters above sea level) in .tiff format, and I need to subtract the value of 10 from the elevation values of cells located within a polygon, which I have in a in .shp format, which I load into python with geopandas, and I want to do this operation without modifying the cells that do not intersect with the polygon. With this I intend to generate a new raster that contains the values to which the subtraction was applied and the unmodified values. The code I am trying to do is the following:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from rasterio.fill import fillnodata
from rasterio.features import geometry_mask
from shapely.geometry import shape
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray as riox
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import xarray as xr
%matplotlib inline 

# Step 1: Open the raster and convert it to a xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray object from riox 
raster_0_riox = riox.open_rasterio('dem_14.tif')

# Step 2: Load the shapefile 
shp_path = 'cuadro_14.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_path)

# Step 3: Get the polygon geometry
geometry = gdf.geometry.iloc[0]
geometry

# Step 4: Make a clip of the raster_riox and plot it
clipped_raster = raster_0_riox.rio.clip([geometry])
clipped_raster.plot()

# Step 5: Review the clipped_raster data
print(clipped_raster)

# Step 6: Subtract 10 from raster_0_riox based on the position of clipped_raster
masked_array = np.ma.masked_where(clipped_raster.rio.isnodata, raster_0_riox.data)
raster_0_minus = raster_0_riox.copy()
raster_0_minus.data = masked_array – 10
```

Step seven is where I get an error that is as follows:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
1 # Paso 7: Restarle 10 al raster_0_riox con base a la posición de clipped_raster
----> 2 masked_array = np.ma.masked_where(clipped_raster.rio.isnodata, raster_0_riox.data)
3 raster_0_minus = raster_0_riox.copy()
4 raster_0_minus.data = masked_array - 10

AttributeError: 'RasterArray' object has no attribute 'isnodata'

I've been looking for how to solve it but I haven't found a solution. If you could guide me with this code. I have also tried the following code;

```
# Convertir a matrices NumPy
raster_0_matrix = raster_0_riox.data[0]
clipped_matrix = clipped_raster.data[0]

# Obtener la máscara de nodata de clipped_raster
clipped_mask = clipped_raster.rio.nodata

# Buscar las posiciones válidas en clipped_raster
rows, cols = np.where(clipped_matrix != clipped_mask)
print(rows)
print(cols)

# Crear una nueva matriz con las dimensiones y coordenadas correctas
raster_01 = np.zeros_like(raster_0_matrix)
raster_01[rows, cols] = raster_0_matrix[rows, cols] – 10

# Crear un nuevo raster con la misma resolución espacial, forma, tamaño y CRS
new_raster = rasterio.open(
    'new_raster.tif',
    'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    height=raster_0_riox.sizes['y'],
    width=raster_0_riox.sizes['x'],
    count=1,
    dtype=str(raster_0_matrix.dtype),
    crs=raster_0_riox.rio.crs,
    transform=raster_0_riox.rio.transform(),
)
new_raster.write(raster_01, 1)
new_raster.close()
# Visualizar el resultado
new_raster_riox = riox.open_rasterio('new_raster.tif')
new_raster_riox.plot()
plt.show()
```

This works better but it modifies the wrong area so I've already lost the thread of what else to do, if someone can tell me the error in code.

[image]

Comment: have a look at GeoCube package, it does what you want, no time to write full answer now... Then do something with a `where(bla)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a modified raster with the same extent as the original where the values are 0 outside the polygon and -10 inside it. Then sum the rasters:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from shapely import wkt

input_rasterfile = r"C:/GIS/data/testdata/rasters/nh_72_6.tif"
output_rasterfile = r"C:/GIS/data/testdata/rasters/nh_72_6_MODIFIED.tif"

#Create a polygon
wktstring = 'Polygon ((614073.48228279908653349 7285609.05735910311341286, 616766.32506066712085158 7285609.05735910311341286, 616766.32506066712085158 7286736.97379120439291, 614073.48228279908653349 7286736.97379120439291, 614073.48228279908653349 7285609.05735910311341286))'
polygon = wkt.loads(wktstring)

#Mask the raster with the polygon
ds = rasterio.open(input_rasterfile, mode="r") #Open the dataset
original_array = ds.read() #Read as an array
masked_array, masked_transform = mask(dataset=ds, shapes=[polygon], nodata=0) #Mask the array with the polygons. Areas outside it get the value 0 
masked_array[masked_array>0]=-100 #Set the values inside the polygon to -100. (I want to subtract 100)

#Sum the original and masked rasters
result = original_array+masked_array #Subtract

#Write the resulting array to file
with rasterio.open(output_rasterfile, mode="w", driver="GTiff", width=result.shape[2], height=result.shape[1],
                   count=1, crs=ds.crs, transform=ds.transform, dtype=result.dtype) as dest:
    dest.write(result)

del(ds) #Close the dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much BERA, it worked perfectly, it generated the new raster with the area where the operation was performed on those specific cells.

Answer (score 0):

With the help provided by BERA here is the code already working:
​

```
# Importar modulos
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from shapely import wkt
import geopandas
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
%matplotlib inline

# Cargar el .shp
gdf = geopandas.read_file(
    "data/cuadro_14.shp",
    crs="epsg:32614",
)
Gdf

# Cargar el raster de entrada y crear el raster de salida
input_rasterfile = r"data/dem_14.tif"
output_rasterfile = r"data/dem_mod.tif"

# Obtenr las coordenadas en in WKT
coordinates = gdf["geometry"].to_numpy()[0]
print(coordinates)

# Crear un polygon
wktstring = "POLYGON ((504259.79059999995 2173996.067500001, 504254.23950000014 2197140.5160000008, 527944.4055000003 2197162.127699999, 527980.8690999998 2174017.4887000006, 504259.79059999995 2173996.067500001))"
polygon = wkt.loads(wktstring)

# Open the dataset
ds = rasterio.open(input_rasterfile, mode="r") #Open the dataset
original_array = ds.read() #Read as an array
masked_array, masked_transform = mask(dataset=ds, shapes=[polygon], nodata=0) #Mask the array with the polygons. Areas outside it get the value 0 
masked_array[masked_array>0]=-10 #Set the values inside the polygon to -100. (I want to subtract 100)
result = original_array+masked_array #Subtract

#Write the resulting array to file
with rasterio.open(output_rasterfile, mode="w", driver="GTiff", width=result.shape[2], height=result.shape[1],
                   count=1, crs=ds.crs, transform=ds.transform, dtype=result.dtype) as dest:
    dest.write(result)

del(ds) #Close the dataset
```

In the images you can see how it works perfectly, in addition to the fact that the output raster maintains the same rows and columns of the original raster.

[image: Modified raster]